# How can I efficiently process a delimited text file?

Tags: c#

I'm simply trying to execute `File.ReadAllLines` against a specific file and, for every line, split on `|`.  I have to use regex on this one.

This code below doesnt work, but you'll see what i'm trying to do:

```
string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
string[] splitlines = Regex.Split(contents, '|');
foreach (string split in splitlines)
{
    //Regex line = content.Split('|');
    //content.Split('|');
    string prefix = prefix = Regex.Match(line, @"(\S+)(\d+)").Groups[0].Value;
    File.AppendAllText(workingdirform2 + "configuration.txt", prefix+"\r\n");
}
```

Comment: when you say "doesn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: also, why does it read "string prefix = prefix = ..."?

Comment: Makes sense it doesnt since you never create a line string. Even in your comment, line is a Regex, which you can't pass to Regex.Split.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you describe what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: BTW: ReadAllLines is really a waste of memory if you're just going to discard it.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure I do know what you're trying to do. Are you trying to split each line into fragments and then append them each into a new line in a file called configuration.txt?

Comment: Perhaps a sample of the data you're trying to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, but there are a number of errors in your code. I have tried to guess what you are doing, but if this isn't what you want, please explain what you do want preferably with some examples:

```
string inputFilename = "input.txt";
string outputFilename = "output.txt";

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText(outputFilename))
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(inputFilename))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            string[] splitlines = line.Split('|');
            foreach (string split in splitlines)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(split, @"\S+\d+");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string prefix = match.Groups[0].Value;
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(prefix);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle match failed...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Key points:

- You seem to want to perform an operation on each line, so you need to iterate over the lines.
- Use the simple string.Split method if you want to split on a single character. Regex.Split doesn't accept a character and "|" has a special meaning in regular expressions so it wouldn't have worked anyway unless you escaped it.
- You were opening and closing the output file multiple times. You should open it just once and keep it open until you have finished writing to it. The `using` keyword is useful here.
- Use WriteLine instead of appending "\r\n".
- If the input file is large, use a `StreamReader` instead of `ReadAllLines`.
- If the match fails, your program will throw an exception. You probably should check `match.Success` before using the match and if this returns false, handle the error appropriately (skip the line, report a warning, throw an exception with an appropriate message, etc.)
- You aren't actually using groups 1 and 2 in the regular expression, so you can remove the parentheses to save the regular expression engine from having to store results that you won't use anyway.

Comment: @Ryan: Good point. He did explicitly ask for an efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Split takes a string, not an array of strings.

I would recommend calling Regex.Split on each item of contents individually, then looping over the results of that call. This would mean nested for loops.

```
string[] contents = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
foreach (string line in contents)
{
    string[] splitlines = Regex.Split(line);
    foreach (string splitline in splitlines)
    {
        string prefix = Regex.Match(splitline, @"(\S+)(\d+)").Groups[0].Value;
        File.AppendAllText(workingdirform2 + "configuration.txt", prefix+"\r\n");
    }
}
```

This, of course isn't the most efficient way to go about it.

A more efficient way might be to split on a regular expression instead. I think this works:

```
string splitlines = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(filename), "$|\\|");
```

Comment: id love to do it that way except i'd have to do a foreach twice and that could consist of building a string about 4 million times.

Comment: yeah cant do that this is going to be long drawn out and complicated abour 4 ints for each output line and possible 2k additional lines for just the 2nd foreach

Comment: See the added second option. Using this (or something similar), you can split the entire file by lines and '|' characters all at once. then do your foreach as before.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should pass the original string to `Regex.Split` and not an array.
2. Looks like you are using `line` instead of `split` when settings the prefix. Without knowing more about your code I cant tell if it's right or not but in any case it sticks out as the error.(it shouldnt build either)
3. This is a really inefficient on at least two levels :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume, based on the limited feedback, that this is what you're looking for:

```
     string inputFile = filename;
     string outputFile = Path.Combine( workingdirform2, "configuration.txt" );
     using ( StreamReader inputFileStream = File.OpenText( inputFile ) ) 
     {           
        using ( StreamWriter ouputFileStream =  File.AppendText( outputFile )  )
        {
           // Iterate over the file contents to extract the prefix
           string currentLine;
           while ( ( currentLine = inputFileStream.ReadLine() ) != null )
           {
              // Notice the updated Regex - your's is a bit broken
              string prefix = Regex.Match( currentLine, @"^(\S+?)\d+" ).Groups[1].Value;
              ouputFileStream.WriteLine( prefix );
           }
        }
     }
```

This would take a file full of:

```
Text1231|abc|abc
Text1232|abc|abc
Text1233|abc|abc
Text1234|abc|abc
```

and place:

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

into a new file.

I hope this, at least, gets you on the right path.  My crystal ball is getting hazy.. haaazzzy..

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the best way to process text files in C# is to use [fileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/). Give it a look. It allows you to strongly type your import data.